# ag-grid copy and paste a cell with double quotation

Tags: javascript, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

Have a question about ag-grid copy&paste.

If a cell contains a double quotation, the strings after this quotation will lose after paste.

https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-clipboard/

Go to the first example of this page, add a grid property "suppressCopyRowsToClipboard=true" to prevent whole row copy. Then change the cell **Michael Phelps** to Michael **Michael Phelps "test"**, and copy this cell. When paste it into another cell, it will be Michael Phelps rather than Michael Phelps "test".

So is it the rule of ag-grid that double quotation cannot be paste?